# PHPUnit HTML code coverage error

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, code-coverage

I have PHPUnit 5.4.6 and PHP 5.6.16 with Xdebug 2.4.0RC2.

The HTML code coverage gives me this error:

```
Undefined property: SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage::$container
```

Some HTML output was actually generated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var baseUrl         = '
```

The PHP framework is Symfony 2. Does it refer to Symfony container or something else? Any ideas where to start the debugging from?

**UPDATE**:

Strangely enough, running some test with the --filter option I got a more complex error message:

```
Notice: Undefined property: PHP_CodeCoverage::$container 
in [...]\src\Index\HomeBundle\Resources\views\Home\404.html.php on line 8
```

So it is Symfony related...

Comment: Can you post the complete output of PHPUnit and not just the one line you posted? Does the problem persist with versions of PHP, PHPUnit, and Xdebug that are actually supported?

Comment: That line is the only error output. I will try with a newer version of PHP / PHPUNIT / Xdebug to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the error is generated by the fact that PHPUNIT analyzed also template files. And that incomplete HTML output was actually the string from a template.

To solve the issue I changed the settings from phpunit.xml to target only the folders needed.

```
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">../src/*/*/Controller/</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">../src/Models/</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```